# The uniqueness of solution of an equation that involves CDFs

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have two monotone CDFs $F(x)$ and $G(x)$. The functions are symmetric in a sense that $F(x)=1-G(1-x)$, $f(x)=g(1-x)$. I am trying to show that equation $xF(2x)+(1-x)G(2x)=1/n$, $n\geq2$ has a unique solution on $[0, 0.5]$. I have not found a counterexample, and simulations show that this is likely to be correct. I would appreciate any ideas how to show this generally.

ps: $xF(2x)+(1-x)G(2x)$ is generally not monotone, and it seems that when it is not, there are 1 local maximum and 1 local minimum, which are above 0.5.